# Host Flask app with nextjs on custom server

Tags: flask, server

This is my first project using flask. I have finished with my project so now I have to deploy it.

I have this file structure:

```
-Root folder

  -client

  -server
```

I wanted to remove pyhton from node since I need to run "setup Python application", but Cpanel doesnt let me run app in client folder. So I want to separate it and run it on the same domain from different folder.

Now I have a problem with hosting the app. Its confusing what else I have to do to host the app but there is no good explanation on the internet.

I tried running waitres which docs says. But although it says it is running, I cant send a request and it returns 404 on the client.

Is there any other way to do this or I am missing something?

I would really appreciate any guide or help to do this. Thanks!